# Site configuration under NGINX: serve static files and .NET files

Tags: .net, nginx, configuration, static-files

I'm trying to get Nginx to serve static content and forward it to .NET too. Sorry if this is simple, I'm new to nginx.

This is my sites-available file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ip_here domain_here;
    root /var/www/html;

    location ^~ /static/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ cat.txt =404;
    }

    location / {
        try_files @dotnet /dev/null dog.txt =404;
    }

    location @dotnet {
        #...
    }

    ##NOTE: THE FOLLOWING WORKED BEFORE I CHANGED IT TO THE ABOVE
    ##location / {
    ##    try_files $uri $uri/ @dotnet;
    ##}
}
```

I changed the commented part to the uncommented part because (1) I needed example.com/ to direct to @dotnet but `try_files /` obviously worked, and (2) people pointed out it was more secure to have a `/static/`.

**When I try to access any path, I get a 404**, not even the debug dog.txt or cat.txt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? URIs beginning with `/static/` are served from a directory `/var/www/html/static/` and URIs not beginning with `/static/` are reverse proxied to whatever is in the `location @dotnet` block?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, but URIs beginning with `/static/` are proxied to `/var/www/html/` directly (there is no static directory) - regardless, even if I had to add a `/static/` directory, that would be fine. As I see it, if I accessed any URI right now, I should be getting cat.txt or dog.txt, which I'm not - just 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `location ^~ /static/` block which processes any URI which begins with `/static/`. The `try_files` directive will test *file parameters* in order to determine if a local file exists at calculated pathname. The pathname is calculated by concatenating the value of the `root` directive with the value of the *file parameter. These *file parameters* should begin with a leading `/`.

In this case:

```
root /var/www/html;
location ^~ /static/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cat.txt =404;
}
```

The URI `/static/foo` will be tested to see if a file exists at `/var/www/html/static/foo`, then a directory at `/var/www/html/static/foo`, then a file at `/var/www/html/cat.txt`, and finally take the default action of returning a 404 status.

Only the last parameter of the `try_files` directive can be status code, named location, or a URI (causing an internal redirection). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

If `cat.txt` is located at `/var/www/html/static/cat.txt`, use:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /static/cat.txt =404;
```

Notice that in both cases, there is a leading `/`.

If there is no directory called `static`, use the `alias` directive instead. But note that `alias` and `try_files` in the same `location` block, [can cause problems](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

---

In this case:

```
try_files @dotnet /dev/null dog.txt =404;
```

The `try_files` statement makes no sense. The named location can only appear in the last position. So the last parameter can be a named location or an `=404`, not both.

There is no need for a `location /` block sending the request to a `location @dotnet`. Just remove the `location /` block and rename the `location @dotnet` block to `location /`.

Comment: The last try_files was a desperate attempt because I can't find the directive to just go to the named location, and try_files requires at least two options. In the future, would I do `try_files /dev/null @dotnet` or can I do something like just `proxy_pass @dotnet`?

Comment: If you must use a named location, I would use `try_files nonexistent @xxx;` - or any bogus name that cannot be a file within the document root. `/dev/null` is ambiguous as it looks like the device `/dev/null` but is actually a non existent URI.